# Using SearchField Inside Popover Keeps on Emitting 'select' Event and Rerenders Popover

Tags: sapui5

I am using a custom control for a popover like this:

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/m/Popover"
], function(Popover) {
  "use strict";

  return Popover.extend("name of controle", {
    init: function() {
      Popover.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
        this.oPopup.setAutoClose(false);
    },

    renderer : "sap.m.PopoverRenderer"

  });
});
```

And I am using this popover custom control like this:

```xml
<core:FragmentDefinition
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  xmlns:path="path to custom popover"
>
  <path:CustomPopover
    placement="Left"
    contentHeight="80%"
    contentWidth="25%"
  >
    <path:content>
      <!-- xmlview that has search field in it -->
    </path:conent>
  </path:CustomPopover>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Now, if I use this fragment to create Popover, then the `select` event keeps on emitting for that search field.

> 2017-02-15 09:53:47.456659 Event fired: 'select' on Element sap.m.SearchField#__field0 -  sap.ui.core.UIArea

This popover works fine in chrome even after continuous emission of an event but in Internet Explorer, it keeps on rerendering, so not able to use it. How to fix this?

Comment: Seems to work for me without any continuous emissions, you can try to stop the Event propagation with oEvent.preventDefault() Method : https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.Event.html#preventDefault

Comment: Sorry I have updated the question I am placing the XML view that has search field inside that.

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to replicate your problem, seems to work for me even with an XML View inside

Comment: Is this issue still reproducible?